# DBUS ofono can not communicate with pulseaudio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, dbus, bluez, pulseaudio

I am trying to set up bluez-5.50 with ofono-1.18 and pulseaudio-12.0 in order to handle phone calls over Bluetooth. However, I'm getting the following problem over dbus-monitor.

```
error time=1539324786.794398 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.28 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied reply_serial=23
   string "Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.28" (uid=0 pid=22288 comm="pulseaudio --realtime ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.25" (uid=0 pid=22285 comm="/usr/sbin/ofonod -d -n ")"
```

My /etc/dbus-1/system.conf is as follows:

```
<policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.pulseaudio"/>
    <allow own="org.pulseaudio.Server"/>
    <allow own="org.ofono"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.ofono"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.ofono.SimToolkitAgent"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.ofono.PushNotificationAgent"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.ofono.SmartMessagingAgent"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.ofono.PositioningRequestAgent"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.ofono.HandsfreeAudioAgent"/>
    <allow own="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Agent1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.ThermometerWatcher1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.AlertAgent1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Profile1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.HeartRateWatcher1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.CyclingSpeedWatcher1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattDescriptor1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>
  </policy>
```

To my understanding, pulseaudio and ofono can not communicate, although I get sound output from ofono to pulseaudio. Another reason might be that pulseaudio is started with pulseaudio --start, but other daemons are started with systemd services.

After a while, ofono disconnects, even Bluetooth disconnects. I suspect this dbus error might be the cause of that. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure ofono is installed

```
sudo apt-get install ofono
```

2. Make sure `pulse` users is created and it is part of `bluetooth` group
3. Grant the permission add this to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf` (inside `<busconfig></busconfig>`):

```
<policy user="pulse">
    <allow send_destination="org.ofono"/> 
</policy>
```